# I am trying to publish an apk on google play and it keeps showing this error

Tags: google-api, google-play-console, androidpublisher

can't parse JSON.  Raw result:

Error uploading APK: 403 Forbidden
POST https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.mobileapp/edits
{
"code" : 403,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "The caller does not have permission",
"reason" : "forbidden"
} ],
"message" : "The caller does not have permission",
"status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}

i was expecting to upload an apk file to a given track.